# Ajax script receiving user string input text and Posting in JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a function ipcfg_set that will set the IP address and it takes the user input variable and sends it in JSON format back to the function. Having issue with constructing the script that takes the IP,mask,gateway entered by user and upon clicking the button will send the value in JSON back.

```
function ipcfg_set () 
               {
                $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'ipcfg_set.cgi',
               dataType : "json",
               data: { ipv4_addr: $('#ip1').val() + '.' + $('#ip2').val() + '.' + $('#ip3').val() + '.' + $('#ip4').val(),
                    gw_addr: $('#gw1').val() + '.' + $('#gw2').val() + '.' + $('#gw3').val() + '.' + $('#ip4').val(), 
                    ipv4_mask: $('#nm1').val() + '.' + $('#nm2').val() + '.' + $('#nm3').val() + '.' + $('#nm4').val()      
                    }
            success: function(data) {

        });
    }


    $(function() {
        $('#btnreset').on('click', ipcfg_get);
        $('#btnapply').on('click', ipcfg_set);
        ipcfg_get();
    });
```

HTML code

```
 <section>

        <h2>IP Configuration</h2>
        <p>Please fill in the form and press <b>Apply</b> to save settings.</p>
        <p>Press <b>Reset</b> to revert settings.</p>
        <section>

        <table class="formgrid">
        <tr><th>IP Address:</th><td><input type="text" name="a1" id="ip1" size="3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="a2" size="3" id="ip2" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="a3" size="3" id="ip3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="a4" size="3" id="ip4" value="0"></td></tr>



                <tr><th>Network mask:</th><td><input type="text" name="m1" id="nm1" size="3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="m2" size="3" id="nm2" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="m3" size="3" id="nm3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="m4" size="3" id="nm4" value="0"></td></tr>

            <tr><th>Gateway:</th><td><input type="text" name="g1" id="gw1" size="3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="g2"  size="3" id="gw2" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="g3" size="3" id="gw3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="g4" size="3" id="gw4" value="0"></td></tr>
        </table>
        </section>
        <section>
        <input id="btnreset" type="button" class="button" value="Reset" />
        <input id="btnapply" type="button" class="button" value="Apply..." />
        </section>
```

Comment: can you show your html ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the values from inputs using function like this, just to reduce typing. You have four inputs per IP address, the function will combine values into the single string:

```
function formatIP(id) { 
    return $(id+'1').val() + '.' + $(id+'2').val() + '.' + 
           $(id+'3').val() + '.' + $(id+'4').val() 
}
```

And the `data` parameter should be a javascript object like this:

```
data: { 
   ipv4_addr: formatIP('#ip'),
   gw_addr:   formatIP('#nm'),
   ipv4_mask: formatIP('#gw')
}
```

Comment: for the html structure i have table rows that are with individual id's and want to convert their string text input to JSON and post the values to the server.

Comment: @jackotonye I updated the answer according to the HTML

Comment: @jackotonye sorry, there was an old version of the function, I updated the answer. It should be `fucntion formatIP(id) {}` and it adds 1, 2, 3, 4 inside, so you just call it as `formatIP('#ip')`.

Comment: @jackotonye but it is actually not really important to this question, you can even have without an additional function, like `data: { ipv4_addr: $('#ip1').val() + '.' + $('#ip2').val() + '.' + $('#ip2').val() + '.' + $('#ip3').val(), ... }`

Comment: upon success i want to update the user input values and change the set ip to the inputed value

Comment: @jackotonye I didn't get your last comment. Also please don't move parts of my answer into your question, it now looks like I just citing your question without adding any useful information.